# cannot insert after soft delete values in prisma ORM

Tags: node.js, prisma

I just need an idea about this. I have created a table with a unique column named `person_name`. In this table I use prisma v2 soft delete method. In here just update the deleted column as true.

But when I try to insert the same `person_name` after a soft delete, it returns an error calling Unique constraint failed.

Can anybody give any idea to skip this issue. My requirement is to make `person_name` as a unique column. But when I delete the `person_name` I should be able to insert the same `person_name` again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique column index on the `person_name` field then even if you mark the record as soft deleted, it still exists in the table due to which you are getting the unique constraint failed error.

You actually need to create a partial unique index where only the fields which are not soft deleted are included in the unique index and the deleted ones are not included.

You can do something like this:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX soft_delete ON user (name) WHERE (is_deleted is NOT true);
```